# Pygame: Problems with pointing image to mouse

Tags: python, image, math, pygame, angle

From my understanding, this:

`angle_to_pointer = degrees(atan2((py+32)-mouse[0], px-mouse[1]))+90`

is a good way to get the angle between points..

I have this image:

[image]

and I'm trying to make it point to the mouse with this script:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from math import degrees,atan2

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

arrow=pygame.image.load('arrow.png')
px=30
py=30
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,255))
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle_to_pointer = degrees(atan2((py+32)-mouse[0], px-mouse[1]))+90
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()
    spr=pygame.transform.rotate(arrow,angle_to_pointer)
    screen.blit(spr,(px,py))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

It appears to work at first, but upon closer inspection, it appears to be pointing a little bit away from the mouse.

I tried fiddling with the values, but the result never came out the way I wanted it to, the code I posted contains the best combination I could create.

Could someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: you are comparing the mouse position to the corner of the image, not its center

Comment: I see.. why doesn't `py+32` because the image is 32x65, shouldn't that be the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is getting too much for a comment.  In your `angle_to_pointer` calculation you are offsetting your mouse in the `Y` coordinate by 32, which puts you at the bottom left of your unrotated image.  you probably ment to add the 32 to the `X` coordinate which would put you on the center for `X` but still off on the `Y`. Also I think your mouse coordinates are backwards.

Even if you added 16 to the `Y` and 32 to the `X` this is still all based on the unrotated image.  Once you rotate the image your size will change.  The easiest way I can think of to do what you are wanting is to not draw your image off of the top left, but use the center.  Find the point you want to be the center and base your `angle_to_pointer` off that. Then when you `blit` use the new rotated image size to find the top left.

for example:
your image is 64x32 so for fun, lets use the point (37,37) as our center (to keep it from going over the edge of the screen)

```
px=37  # center of arrow
py=37  # center of arrow
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,255))
    mouseX, mouseY=pygame.mouse.get_pos()  # unpack to avoid confustion
    angle_to_pointer = degrees(atan2(mouseY - py, mouseX - px))  # calculate off center of image
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    spr=pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, -angle_to_pointer) # clockwise rotation
    # adjust draw top left based on center and rotated image size
    blit_pos = (px - spr.get_width()//2, py - spr.get_height//2)
    screen.blit(spr, blit_pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**disclaimer, haven't tried this since my work computer doesn't have pygame,

Comment: I changed up your code, and it worked great, thanks!